# GAE how to serve an html file dynamically from the server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, servlets, dynamic

I'm working with GAE (Java) in my GWT application.

When my users enter a certain URL I'd like to dynamically create an html page on the server side and serve it to the client.

How can I do this? Using HttpServlet?

I'm quite lost here, do I need to have an html template file on the server side that I dynamically complete and serve to the client?

Comment: I'd like to prefer JSP in such cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with the tutorial to learn the basics. You can generate the whole HTML dynamically, but that tends to get awkward. It's better to separate the HTML to a template and fill in the details with the logic implemented in the GAE application.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like this one https://github.com/alexmuntean/java-url-rewrite . Read the readme to understand more.

You can just take the request and serve anything you want (jsp, jsf, html static). And you can also write gwt code to do actions(effects or ajax for more things. Etc) with the existing html (just add ids to elements) And write another entry point for that page and just include the generated js in your page

I am planning to do a tutorial and POC on how to make a gwt website indexable by google

Comment: Thanks Alex. The motivation behind my question was indeed to be able to dynamically add metatags on the server side to the served webpage so that google can index it correctly. Such a tutorial would be very much welcome. Please drop the link here whenever you have it ready!

Comment: what you need to know is that you can also do this from GWT and that google can index your javascript website :)